# g++ is not producing an error when it should, e.g. "error: variable length array of non-POD element type"

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu, g++

In my C++ program at some point I do:

```
std::cin >> my_int;
my_class my_array[my_int];
```

When I compile it with `g++` on OSX, I get:

> error: variable length array of non-POD element type

as expected. However, when I compile it on Ubuntu, I do not get any errors. In both scenarios I compile with no options.

For reference, `g++ --version` on OSX outputs:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

while on Ubuntu it outputs:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Any ideas on why I do not get the error?

P.S.: I tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get install g++` but for some reason I get as a response that I have the latest version, which if I am not mistaken is 4.9.0, which I do not have...

Comment: As you can see, the "g++" on your OS X system is actually clang.

Comment: Correct, however the reason why `g++` does not throw an error still remains a mystery.

Comment: No compiler is required to report an error with invalid C++ code.  They are all allowed to implement "language extensions" that produce a working binary from code that might not compile.  **In short:** you should expect *correct* C++ to compile, but you should have **no expectations** for *incorrect* C++.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Every *conforming* C++ compiler is required to issue at least one diagnostic message for any program that violates certain rules. g++ is not a conforming C++ compiler by default.

Comment: @KeithThompson very interesting!  Thanks for sharing that.  I'm past my editing window, so +1 up there and down below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any conforming ISO C++ compiler is required to issue a diagnostic for that error. More precisely, it's required to issue at least one diagnostic message for any program that violates certain rules given in the ISO standard.

`g++` is not a fully conforming C++ compiler by default.

To make it (attempt to) conform to the C++ standard, use the `-pedantic` option, preferably along with an option to specify an edition of the C++ standard.

For example, when I compile something similar to your program, g++ does not give any warnings by default -- but when I compile it with

```
g++ -pedantic
```

or

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic`
```

I get:

```
c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cpp:5:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘my_array’ [-Wvla]
```

For more information on g++'s conformance to the C++ standard(s), see the manual; type `info g++` and read the ["Standards"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Standards.html) and ["C++ Extensions"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html) sections (links are to an online version of the manual).

Answer (score 0):

GCC supports some non-standard extensions, one of which is variable length arrays of *certain* non-POD types.

Clang on the other hand, strives to be much more standards compliant.

From the [Clang compatibility FAQ](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla):

> GCC and C99 allow an array's size to be determined at run time. This
>   extension is not permitted in standard C++. However, Clang supports
>   such variable length arrays in very limited circumstances for
>   compatibility with GNU C and C99 programs:
>
> - The element type of a variable length array must be a POD ("plain old data") type, which means that it cannot have any user-declared
>     constructors or destructors, any base classes, or any members of
>     non-POD type. All C types are POD types.
> - Variable length arrays cannot be used as the type of a non-type template parameter.

As @Brian pointed out, you're using Clang on your OSX machine (no surprise, Apple created LLVM) and GCC on your Ubuntu box.

Comment: gcc/g++ does strive to be standards compliant if you ask it nicely by using the `-pedantic` option. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24748113/827263).